# Delete folder if it exists

Tags: command-line, rm

I need to delete folder, subfolders and files if it exists. I am trying to do the following:

```
if [ ! -d folder ]; then rm -rf folder; fi
```

However it doen't work. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Given the seeming mistake understanding `! -d`, you may want to call `rm --preserve-root -rf folder` in case `folder` somehow becomes `\`

Comment: just wondering why it's needed to check if the folder exists... a simple `rm -rf`without check should be enough, because if it doesnot exist, it cannot be removed... or do i miss spmething?

Comment: nice and easy question, specially useful for CI where a rm -rf on a non-existing folder could return a failure instead of a 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if [ ! -d folder ]` part is wrong.  It's false on both empty and non empty directories.  The exclamation mark is the logical not operator: you're checking if the directory does not exist before you delete it.

Remove that exclamation mark.